# copy files from SP library to anther library in other site collection

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

i need to copy files from SP library to anther library  in other site collection, what are the possible ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can achieve this using REST and Sharepoint services to copy files across site collections
you can find more details in the below link
[Update List Item Across Site Collection Using Rest Services And Copy Files From One Library To Another Using SP Services](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/update-list-item-across-site-collection-using-rest-services-and-copy-files-from-one-library-to-another-using-sp-services)